# Get meta tags with guzzle client

Tags: php, guzzle

I have a code:

```
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
$response = $client->request('GET', 'http://example.com');
$meta $response->body(true)['meta']; //get meta description
```

I need get meta description content from a site. How I can do it? My solution is not working.. I get error: undefined index meta

Comment: What URL using ?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need Guzzle

```
$tags = get_meta_tags('http://www.example.com/');

echo $tags['author'];
echo $tags['keywords'];     
echo $tags['description'];
```

or

```
$content = $response->body();
$tags = get_meta_tags($content);
```

Comment: I get error: http request failed 403 forbidden, if I use `get_meta_tags`. If I go manually to site, then it online.

Comment: $content = $response->body();
$tags = get_meta_tags($content);

Answer (score 0):

Using `get_meta_tags` function

```
ini_set('user_agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.7; rv:7.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/7.0.1');
$meta_tags = get_meta_tags('www.example.com');
```

Using `curl`

```
$user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.109 Safari/537.36';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $user_agent);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://example.com");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

print_r($data);
```